# Eigen3 (cpp) select column given mask and sum where true

Tags: c++, openmp, vectorization, eigen, eigen3

I have a `Eigen::Matrix2Xf` where row are X and Y positions and cols act as list index

I would like to have the sum of the columns (rowwise) where some column condition is true, here some example code:

```
Eigen::Vector2f computeStuff(Eigen::Matrix2Xf & values, const float max_norm){

    const auto mask = values.colwise().norm().array() < max_norm;

    return mask.select(values.colwise(), Eigen::Vector2f::Zero()).rowwise().sum();
    
}
```

But this code does not compile complaining about the types of the if/else matrices, what is the correct (and computationally faster) way to do it?

Also I know that there are similar question with an answer, but they create a new `Eigen::Matrix2Xf` with the filtered values given the mask, this code is meant to run inside a `#pragma omp parallel for` so the basic idea is to do not create a new matrix for maintaining cache coherency

Thanks

Comment: Say `values` is 2x4 ... thats 2 rows and 4 columns. Then `values.colwise().norm().array() < max_norm` will be 1x4, one row and four columns. You then say you want to sum the rows in `values` that `mask` selects ... `values` only contains 2 rows and `mask` has four columns. Do you mean you want to sum the *columns* in `values` that the mask selects?

Comment: @jwezorek yeah, exactly that, sorry if i was not clear, I fixt the question

Comment: the other thing is  how can the output be a `vector2f`? The output if i understand what you are trying to do will be a row vector with however many columns the input has. If you want it to only have the non-zero columns and know there will only be two or something  you can't do that with `.select(...)`.

Comment: the output would be a `vector2f`, the idea is to mask out some columns of matrix values, then do a rowwise reducing operation

I want only to have the rowwise sum of the masked columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that `.select( ... )` needs at least one of its arguments to have the same shape as the mask. The arguments can be two matrices or a matrix and a scalar or vice-versa, but in all cases the matrices have to be shaped like the mask.

In your code `mask` is a row vector but `values` is a 2 by *x* matrix. One way to handle this is to just replicate the row vector into a two row matrix:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

Eigen::Vector2f computeStuff(Eigen::Matrix2Xf& values, const float max_norm) {

    auto mask = (values.colwise().norm().array() < max_norm).replicate(2, 1);
    return mask.select(values, 0).rowwise().sum();
}

int main() {

    Eigen::Matrix2Xf mat(2,4);
    mat << 1, 4, 3, 2, 
           1, 2, 4, 3;

    auto val = computeStuff(mat, 5);

    std::cout << val;

    return 0;
}
```

In the above `mask` will be:

```
1 1 0 1
1 1 0 1
```

i.e. the row `1 1 0 1` duplicated once. Then `mask.select(values, 0)` yields

```
1 4 0 2
1 2 0 3
```

so the result will be

```
7
6
```

which i think is what you want, if I am understanding the question.